# Product and Quotient rules in Calculus

Tags: calculus

What is the slope of the tangent line to the function $$g(x)=x^2 \frac{\cos x}{1+x^3}$$ when $x=\pi/2$?
When $x=a$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) Have you attempted anything? It is customary to show what you have attempted the question...or describe the particular aspect that you do not understand so we can better help you.

Comment: How is defined the slope of the tangent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the derivative
$$g'(x)= \{\frac{x^2\cos x}{1+x^3}\}'
\\=\frac{(1+x^3)(2x\cos x-x^2\sin x)-(x^2\cos x)(3x^2)}{(1+x^3)^2}$$
Second the slope is $m=g'(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is calculated using the quotient rule,

$$y=\frac{u}{v} \\ y'=\frac{u'v - v'u}{v^2}$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{(1+x^3)(2x\cos x-x^2\sin x)-(x^2\cos x)(3x^2)}{(1+x^3)^2}$$
The slope of the tangent line in calculus is the limit of the rise over run of the tangent at the tangent point - i.e. $dy/dx$ which is the derivative of the function.

The slopes at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ would be,

$$g'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{-(\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{1+(\frac{\pi}{2})^3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, whenever I see trig functions, i get nervous